# Query reg code in List::Util::reduce

Tags: perl

I came across the following code in List::Util for reduce subroutine.

```
my $caller = caller;
local(*{$caller."::a"}) = \my $a;
local(*{$caller."::b"}) = \my $b;
```

I could understand that reduce function is called as:

```
my $sum = reduce { $a + $b } 1 .. 1000;
```

So, I understood the code is trying to reference $a mentioned in the subroutine. But, I am unable to understand the intent correctly.

For reference, I am adding the complete code for subroutine

```
sub reduce (&@) {
  my $code = shift;
  require Scalar::Util;
  my $type = Scalar::Util::reftype($code);
  unless($type and $type eq 'CODE') {
    require Carp;
    Carp::croak("Not a subroutine reference");
  }
  no strict 'refs';

  return shift unless @_ > 1;

  use vars qw($a $b);

  my $caller = caller;
  local(*{$caller."::a"}) = \my $a;
  local(*{$caller."::b"}) = \my $b;

  $a = shift;
  foreach (@_) {
    $b = $_;
    $a = &{$code}();
  }

  $a;
}
```

Comment: What part *exactly* needs explanation? The typeglob with `*{"..."}`, the general algorithm or why you'd want to `reduce` anything?

Comment: Usage of "local(*{$caller."::a"})". What it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following aliases package variable `$foo` to variable `$bar`.

```
*foo = \$bar;
```

Any change to one changes the other as both names refer to the same scalar.

```
$ perl -E'
   *foo = \$bar;
   $bar=123; say $foo;
   $foo=456; say $bar;
   say \$foo == \$bar ? 1 : 0;
'
123
456
1
```

Of course, you can fully qualify `*foo` since it's a symbol table entry. The following aliases package variable `$main::foo` to `$bar`.

```
*main::foo = \$bar;
```

Or, if you don't know the name at compile time

```
my $caller = 'main';
*{$caller."::foo"} = \$bar;   # Symbolic reference
```

`$bar`, of course, can just as easily be a lexical variable as a package variable. And since `my $bar;` actually returns the variable begin declared,

```
my $bar;
*foo = \$bar;
```

can be written as

```
*foo = \my $bar;
```

So,

```
my $caller = caller;
local(*{$caller."::a"}) = \my $a;
local(*{$caller."::b"}) = \my $b;
```

declares and aliases lexical variables `$a` and `$b` the similarly named package variables in the caller's namespace.

`local` simply causes everything to return to their original state once the sub is exited.

Answer (score 1):

#### On scope

Perl has two variable name scoping mechnisms: global and lexical. Declaration of lexical vars is done with `my`, and they are accessibly by this name until they encounter a closing curly brace.

Global variables, on the other hand, are accessible from anywhere and do not have a scope. They can be declared with `our` and `use vars`, or do not have to be declared if `strict` is not in effect. However, they have *namespaces*, or `packages`. The namespace is a prefix seperated from the variable name by two colons (or a single quote, but never do that). Inside the package of the variable, the variable can be accessed with or without the prefix. Outside of the package, the prefix is required.

The `local` function is somewhat special and gives global variables a temporary value. The scope of this value is the same as that of a lexical variable plus the scopes of all subs called within this scope. The old value is restored once this scope is exited. This is called *the dynamic scope*.

#### On Globs

Perl organizes global variables in a big hash representing the namespace and all variable names (sometimes called the *stash*). In each slot of this hash, there is a so-called glob. A typeglob is a special hash that has a field for each of Perls native types, e.g. scalar, array, hash, IO, format, code etc. You assign to a slot by passing the glob a reference of a value you want to add - the glob figures out the right slot on it's own. This is also the reason you can have multiple variables with the same name (like `$thing`, `@thing`, `%thing`, `thing()`). Typeglobs have a special *sigil*, namely the asterisk `*`.

#### On `no strict 'refs'`

The `no strict 'refs'` is a cool thing if you know what you are doing. Normally you can only dereference normal references, e.g.

```
my @array = (1 .. 5);
my $arrayref = \@array; # is a reference
push @{$arrayref}, 6; # works
push @{array}, 6; # works; barewords are considered o.k.
push @{"array"}, 6; # dies horribly, if strict refs enabled.
```

The last line tried to dereference a string, this is considered bad practice. However, under `no strict 'refs'`, we can access a variable of which we do not know the name at compile time, as we do here.

#### Conclusion

The `caller` functions returns the name of the package of the calling code, i.e. it looks up one call stack frame. The name is used here to construct the full names of `$a` and `$b` variables of the calling packages, so that they can be used there without a prefix. Then, these names are `local`ly (i.e. in the dynamic scope) assigned to the reference of a newly declared, lexical variable.

The global variables `$a` and `$b` are predeclared in each package.

In the `foreach` loop, these lexicals are assigned different values (lexical vars take precedence over global vars), but the global variables `$foo::a` and `$foo::$b` point to the same data because of the reference, allowing the anonymous callback sub in the `reduce` call to read the two arguments easily. (See ikegamis answer for details on this.)

All of this hassle is good because (a) the effects are not externaly visible, and (b) the callback doesn't have to do tedious argument unpacking.